# Modificar el área de captura de un div con html2canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html5

tengo un problema que me gustaría que orientaran a resolverlo.

Uso `html2canvas` para capturar un diagrama de gantt:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La única forma de poder capturar todo el contenido es agregando en mi .css la siguiente linea:

```
.html2canvas-container { width: 3000px !important; }
```

Pero los diagramas varían de tamaños entonces debo cambiar constantemente el atributo. He intentado usar `javascript` para cambiarlo, pero en ninguna parte mando a traer dicha clase así que no puedo modificarlo directamente.

```
var datos = document.getElementById("item").clientWidth;
var titulos = document.getElementById("titulos").clientWidth;
var imagen = datos+titulos;    
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.style.width = imagen;
```

El detalle esta que cuando ejecuto debería modificar el tamaño de la captura, pero en su lugar no cambia nada por que no modifica la clase `html2canvas-container`. También he intentado con `variable.className("clase");` sin éxito alguno por que no puedo traer directamente la clase pues yo no uso en mi código ni la mando a traer en ningún momento.

Comment: Deberías poner un ejemplo del HTML que tienes y explicar un poco más cómo quieres trabajar con el ancho de ese div

Answer (score 0):

**Intenta con:**

```
.html2canvas-container { width: auto !important; }
```